# Is it natural to omit "for example" when giving examples

Tags: word-usage

Consider the following sentence

> The story has been made into different kinds of entertainment, **for example**, games, novels, comics, TV series and movies.

Is it natural to omit "for example" here, especially in writing, to make the sentence shorter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just omitting it doesn't work. These substitutions do.

A colon  "...entertainment: games, novels..."
e.g.  "...entertainment, e.g., games, novels..." (e.g. can be read as "for example")
like "...entertainment, like games, novels..."
such as "...entertainment, such as games, novels..."
to wit  "...entertainment, to wit, games, novels..." (old-fashioned or stilted)